# How to link on block

Tags: nodes, blocks

I work on D8. I Create to custom block with display content and Read More option. The URL alias is about_us of `node/2`,  I want to add read more link with `node/2` and show about_us on URL.

Comment: add a text field, with full html then put `<a href="/about_us">Read More</a>`

Comment: This is not standard code, In D7 use <?php echo url('node/2'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

If you have created that custom block using a view , yo can easily add link to the respective node.You can add `content: link` in the FIELDS section

[image]

Comment: Custom block create not using a view. just by url block/add and link to any content page (node/1 or node/2 or node/3), not respective node.